# Delphi REST request async cannot populate TList

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have declared these new types:

```
type
 TRacer = record
  name: string;
  win, tie, loss, points: integer;
 end;

 TRacersList = TList<TRacer>;
```

I have a procedure in a datamodule that looks like this:

```
procedure DMConnection.getDivision(aList: TRacersList; const game, id: string);
begin

 //1) setup the REST params
 RESTRequest.Params[0].Value := game;
 RESTRequest.Params[1].Value := id;

 //2) execute async so UI won't freeze
 RESTRequest.ExecuteAsync(procedure
 var tmp: TRacer;
    ja: TJSONArray;
    jv: TJSONValue;
 begin

  //parse the JSON. The RESTResponse is a TRESTResponse that holds the result of the RESTRequest. I have made a test inside the component (right click -> execute) and it works properly (= I can see the JSON inside the Content property).
  ja := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(RESTResponse.Content) as TJSONArray;

  for jv in ja do begin
   tmp.name := jv.GetValue<string>('name');
   tmp.win := jv.GetValue<integer>('Wins');
   tmp.tie := jv.GetValue<integer>('Ties');
   tmp.loss := jv.GetValue<integer>('Loss');
   tmp.points := jv.GetValue<integer>('Pts');

   aList.Add(tmp);
  end;

 end);

end;
```

If you are wondering, this is the JSON string:

```
[{"name":"payer1","Wins":"1","Ties":"0","Loss":"0","Pts":"3"},{"name":"Velocity","Wins":"0","Ties":"0","Loss":"1","Pts":"0"},{"name":"test2","Wins":"0","Ties":"0","Loss":"0","Pts":"0"}]
```

In the main form I am able to call the procedure in this way:

```
DMConnection.getDivision(myList, 'mku', 'k2');
```

---

I have the following problem. The variable `myList: TRacersList` is created and freed in the OnCreate and OnDestroy events of the form. If you try to run this code:

```
DMConnection.getDivision(myList, 'mku', 'k2');
ShowMessage(myList.Count.toString);
```

The result is 0. Instead, if I put the `aList.Add(tmp);` **OUTSIDE** the async request (for example, before the parameters setup) the count is 1.

This means that the list is being filled when it's outside the completion handler of the `ExecuteAsync` but when the list is inside it doesn't. Any idea?

I have cheched that by default the Synchronize is set to True, so adding

```
TTHread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
begin
 aList.Add(tmp);
end)
```

Would be useless. What should I do? I'd like to have this parsing/rest stuff in the datamodule so I can keep the internet stuff separated from my app implementation.

Comment: Since the REST GET is async, the call DMConnection.getDivision returns inmediately w/o the json beign parsed nor the list populated, therefore, you got an empty list

Comment: @Agustin, it's not so. The anonymous method passed to the call is the completion method, which is even executed in the main thread (because `ASynchronized` parameter remains enabled).